# How can I check if a specific value exists in a list?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check the value of all li tags in a ul list.
If any list item contains the value of "None" then it must add specific text into a div. If no li tag contains the value of "None" then different text must be added to the div.

I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "includes", mylist.textContent is undefined

So it seems that I'm not using the .includes() method correctly.

```js
var mydiv = document.querySelector("#mydiv");
var mylist = document.querySelectorAll("#mylist li");
var myresult = mylist.textContent.includes("None");

if (myresult == true) {
  mydiv.textContent = "Result is True";
} else {
  mydiv.textContent = "Result is False";
}
```

```html
My HTML:

<ul id="mylist">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>None</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ul>

<ul id="mydiv">
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't get the text content of a list of elements. You have to look at them individually.

Comment: So the error is upstream of where you seem to think it is. The critical portion is `mylist.textContent is undefined`. That means that `querySelectorAll` doesn't have a `textContent` property.

Comment: @isherwood okay, so am I supposed to loop through the "mylist" array, check their .textContent individually, then add the result of each to a new array before using the .includes() method?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava This has nothing to do with my question

Comment: It does, if you look closely. Everything in-fact

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava No it doesnt - That user compared getElementsByClassName with getElementById I am well aware that the one is a plural and the other not. I didn't even use getElementsByClassName in my code.

Comment: When a dup is linked, please also read the answers, instead of just the question.

Comment: For your problem, `querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements, so we cannot get `textContent` of a single element on that list. You can check my answer for a better understanding too. @Shtarley

Answer (score 0):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of elements, so you cannot check [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of a particular element

I'd suggest that you should convert your list to an array with [a spreading operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (to be able to use array functions) and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check your condition

```js
var mydiv = document.querySelector("#mydiv");
var mylist = document.querySelectorAll("#mylist li");
var myresult = [...mylist].some(item => item.textContent.includes("None"));

if (myresult === true) {
  mydiv.textContent = "Result is True";
} else {
  mydiv.textContent = "Result is False";
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>None</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ul>

<ul id="mydiv">
</ul>
```